# Procedimento não sendo executado em Portugol Studio

Tags: funções, portugol, portugol-studio

Eu criei um código para receber o: nomes, idade, sexo e salário de 10 pessoas, uma função para ordenar os vetores de acordo com o maior salário, e outra função para retornar os nomes das 5 mulheres melhores remuneradas.

Porém quando eu termino de preencher o código com as informações, ele não retorna nada e também não encerra, fica como se estivesse esperando alguma informação.

Alguma ideia de qual é o erro?

```
programa
{ 
    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro salario[10], idade[10], tamanho, z = 0, x = 0
        cadeia nome[10], sexo[10]
        para(inteiro a = 0 ; a < 10 ; a++){
            escreva("Insira o nome do funcionário: ")
            leia(nome[a])
            escreva("Insira o salário arrendondado do funcionário: ")
            leia(salario[a])
            enquanto(salario[a] < 0){
                escreva("Não é possivel ter um salario negativo, insira novamente: ")
                leia(salario[a])
            }
            escreva("Insira a idade do funcionário: ")
            leia(idade[a])
            enquanto(idade[a] < 12 ou idade[a] > 99){
                 escreva("Insira uma idade válida (maior que 12 e menor que 99): ")
                 leia(idade[a])
            }
            escreva("Insira o sexo do funcionário: (Masculino 'M' | Feminino 'F'): ")
            leia(sexo[a])
            enquanto(sexo[a] != "M" e sexo[a] != "F"){
                escreva("Insira 'M' para Masculino | 'F' para Feminino: ")
                leia(sexo[a])
            }       
                limpa()
        }   
        ordenarsalarios(salario, idade, nome, sexo)
        
    }

     funcao ordenarsalarios(inteiro salario[],inteiro idade[], cadeia nome[],cadeia sexo[]){
        inteiro aux, aux1
          cadeia aux2, aux3

              para(inteiro a = 0 ; a < 10 ; a++){
                para(inteiro b = 0 ; b < 10 ; b++){
                    se(salario[a] > salario[b]){
                    aux = salario[a]
                    salario[a] = salario[b]
                    salario[b] = aux

                    aux1 = idade[a]
                    idade[a] = idade[b]
                    idade[b] = aux1

                    aux2 = nome[a]
                    nome[a] = nome[b]
                    nome[b] = aux2
                    
                    aux3 =  sexo[a]
                    sexo[a] = sexo[b]
                    sexo[b] = aux3
                    }
                }
              }
          b(salario, idade, nome, sexo)
     }

        funcao b(inteiro salario[],inteiro idade[], cadeia nome[],cadeia sexo[]){
              
              cadeia nomescrever[5]
              inteiro controle = 0, k = 0
              para(inteiro a = 0 ; a < 10 ; a++){
                se(sexo[a] == "F"){
                    controle++
                    enquanto(controle < 5){
                        nomescrever[controle-1] = nome[a]
                    }
                }   
              }
              escreva("=======\n")
              escreva("Os nomes das 5 mulheres melhores remuneradas são: \n")
              para(inteiro esc = 0 ; esc < 5 ; esc++){
                escreva(esc+1,"º - ",nomescrever[esc],"\n")
              }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você teria que por as variáveis globais fora da função para quando sair da função os dados ficar guardado e ai sim mandar escrever na tela os conteúdo.

Comment: A atividade pede para que não se use variáveis globais, como eu faria para passar os dados sem a utilização delas?

Comment: Blz edita a pergunta e coloca essa informação lá porque ai fica difícil para adivinhar :D

Comment: Cria as função para ordenar o maior salário, e a função para retornar os nomes das 5 mulheres. na procedure principal você vai pegar todos os dados e depois chamar as funções para facilita, você já colocar um array para guardar a ordenação e um para guardar as mulheres mas bem pagas.
Na hora de printar você printa a array correspondente.